# Crates in watch dogs is missing

Tags: watch-dogs

I didn't start the campaign myself, but I have picked up pretty early on in the game, but I am trying to finish all of the weapons trade missions. I have completed all of the ones that are displayed on the map and have hacked into all of the ctOS towers. Is it possible to find the crate and not scan it but still have it disappear from the map?

Comment: How many have you done? IIRC the 11th mission appears later, after a phonecall or something. I can't remember exactly. Also, I think you might have to complete certain sections of the campaign to unlock some side missions. I had completed the campaign before I did the missions, so I can't say which, or if that applies to weapon trade missions.

Comment: I am not sure what happened, but after a couple restarts the weapons crate counter caught back up.